# Mysql Join with WHERE min(value)

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have this problem

I have 2 Tables

```
1. product_detail
-id
-name
-thumb

2. product_sale
-id
-pid
-fid
-price
-package
```

.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM product_sale 
 WHERE MIN(product_sale.price) 
 JOIN product_detail 
   ON product_detail.id = product_sale.pid
```

ORIGINAL SELECT SORRY POSTED WRONG

```
SELECT * FROM product_detail INNER JOIN product_sale ON product_detail.id = pid
```

I Have 1 Product in product_detail Example Product1
I Have Many rows in product_sale for Product1 but different product_sale.fid and product_sale.price

What i need to do ist make a select that display Product1 With Lovest Price in product_sale

```
1 Product1 1.50 1pz
2 Product2 2.50 3pz
3 Product3 3.00 1pz
```

Now i Get

```
1 Product1 1.50 1pz
2 Product1 1.65 1pz
3 Product1 1.70 1pz
4 Product3 3.00 1pz
```

Please helpme what select i need to do ??Thank You All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barring subqueries, you can't JOIN after a WHERE, and I am pretty sure you can't use MIN in a WHERE either. However, you can WHERE a subquery that contains a MIN.

```
SELECT * 
FROM product_sale AS ps INNER JOIN product_detail AS pd ON ps.pid = pd.id
WHERE (ps.pid, ps.price) IN (
   SELECT pid, MIN(price) 
   FROM product_sale 
   GROUP BY pid
);
```

Note that if the product is sold at the lowest price multiple times, you will get multiple rows for it. I am not clear on what the #pz values are supposed to be, but perhaps the `*` in my answer should be `pd.id, pd.name, COUNT(1) AS pz` and `GROUP BY pd.id, pd.name` placed before the `;`

Edit: The below should get the "last sale" asked about in the comments below this answer.

```
SELECT * 
FROM product_sale AS ps3 
    INNER JOIN product_detail AS pd ON ps3.pid = pd.id
WHERE ps3.fid IN (
    SELECT MAX(ps2.fid) AS lastFidsForPidsAtLowestPrices
    FROM product_sale AS ps2
    WHERE (ps2.pid, ps2.price) IN (
        SELECT ps1.pid, ps1.MIN(price) AS lowestPriceForPid
        FROM product_sale AS ps1
        GROUP BY ps1.pid
        )
    GROUP BY ps2.pid
    )
;
```

Comment: Ok, then you might want `SUM(ps.package)` instead of `COUNT(1)`.

Comment: Please Cann you tell me what product_sale AS ps ist just renaming the table ?? and GROUP BY pid ?? what ist ist order list or somthing else Thank You

Comment: Yes, `product_sale AS ps` just aliases the table, making for a shorter (and in my opinion more readable) query. The `GROUP BY pid` makes the subquery return the lowest price (because of MIN) for each pid in product_sale. The `WHERE ([fieldlist]) IN ([subquery])` chooses the rows for the "outer" SELECT based on if the specified field values for a row correspond to the field values in the results of the subquery.

Comment: Thank You Please can you Help me for 1 Thinh More!!
If i have 2 or more same prices in product_sale for Product1 then i get 2 or more Product1 in the list with different product_sale.fid how i can display just the one last inserted?? Thank You

Comment: That is a bit more complicated, and I don't have the time right now, but I'll try to remember to get back to it later.

Comment: BTW: Join can occur after a where besides a subuery... UNION :P

Comment: @xQbert, I kind of consider the SELECTs in a UNION as subqueries; but I suppose that is technically true.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a straight forward join with a group by and a min..

```
SELECT PD.name, min(price) as LowestSoldPrice, PD.Thumb, PS.Package
FROM product_Detail PD
LEFT JOIN product_Sale PS
 on PD.ID = PS.PID
GROUP BY PD.name, PD.Thumb, PS.Package
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your query at all. I was surprised it produced anything but an error. This is what I would do.

```
select pd.id productid,
min(pd.name) name, -- min just so I do not have a complex group by
min(ps.price) minprice
from product_detail pd
join product_sale ps
on pd.id=ps.pid
group by pd.id
```

This will give you one row per product ID with the name of the product and the min price.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT ps.*, pd.* 
 FROM product_sale ps
 LEFT JOIN product_sale t
   ON ps.pid = t.pid AND ps.price>t.price
 LEFT JOIN product_detail pd
   ON pd.id = product_sale.pid
WHERE t.pid IS NULL
```

But as many people here I wonder if you really need `GROUP BY`. What is accepted behavior if you have 2 or more sales with the same minimum price? Should all records be returned? or just one? which one then?

Comment: I need just 1 Row with lovest price

Comment: Don't you understand the issue? if you have 2 records with the same min price like: `1 Product1 1.50 1pz`,`17 Product1 1.50 1pz` which one must be returned? does it important for you to get `id` of the record?? what you want to get if Package are different for those 2 records?